# How to open quick create form to edit a record Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

gI have a subgrid in a main form of entity A, when I click in a record in this subgrid, it takes as you know to the record but in the page of sugbrid.
I want to display the quick create form with the information of my record so as I can edit from the form where I have the subgrid.
It is possible in creation mode but I want to do it for edition.
Is there any way to do that in dynamics CRM?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: if their name is "quick create" there is a reason, otherwise they will be called "quick forms"

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but for what you are asking there is no way to update a record from the quick create form for a supported way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom ribbon button that opens a form where you have limited fields and by passing data along with the form data that is already filled in is completed in this limited form.